# Reclaim hashmap data back to a hashmap form a .yml file

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Hello I was creating a Minecraft plugin and was watching a youtube tutorial and explanation on how to store and reclaim data to  a yml file this plugin requires the UUID of a player and stores it along with a chunk from the game and the person in the video was using it in an itemstack array Ias apposed to a UUID sting I tried to convert the code to work with a string but it only gave me more errors and was wondering on how to do it so it does not cover tot an array when it is put back into the hashmap

```
public void restoreClaimedChunks() {
    this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("data").getKeys(false).forEach(key ->{
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        UUID[] content = ((List<UUID>) Objects.requireNonNull(this.getConfig().get("data." + key))).toArray(new UUID[0]);
        chunks.put(key, content);
    });
}
```

the error I receive when I do this is
incompatible types: java.util.UUID[] cannot be converted to java.util.UUID

and the yml file looks like

```
ZeradentSMP: zoren3105.zeradentsmp.ZeradentSMP
name: ZeradentSMP
version: 1.0
author: Zoren
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show the error, and also the yml file ?

Comment: @Elikill58 i have updated the question with the error and yml config file

Answer (score 2):

Since UUID doesn't implement `ConfigurationSerializable` the UUIDs in the YAML file are stored as Strings which means a casting error would occur when you try to cast a list of Strings to a list of UUIDs. Try instead getting a list of Strings from the YAML file (either by casting to `List<String>` or by using [`ConfigurationSection.getStringList()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getStringList(java.lang.String))) and then iterating through to convert each one to a UUID with [`UUID.fromString()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getStringList(java.lang.String)).

**EDIT**

If the error you are receiving is a casting error between `UUID[]` and `UUID` then it appears the only thing that could cause that is if the type of the key in the `chunks` map is `UUID` and you are trying to put a `UUID[]` into it.

You can either change the type of the key in the map or don't get a list of UUIDs from the YAML file.